# Wraptext() function does not work with variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem in Vba. When I use Wraptext() with variable it does not work

```
Dim v_row as Long

v_row = 4

Sheets(1).Range("B" & v_row).WrapText = True
```

I tried this too, but it does not work either :

```
Dim v_row as Long
    
v_row = 4
    
Sheets(1).Range("B" & CStr(v_row)).WrapText = True
```

And the column seems like this:

[image]

But It does work like this:

```
Sheets(1).Range("B4").WrapText = True
```

and afer that the column look like this:

[image]

Comment: Your first  code works perfectly for me. Are you sure is not working? Maybe you have a public variable called `v_row ` somewhere else? Does this code execute inside a process? Have you tried debugging it and see what error arises? You said *it does not work*, but that's unclear.

Comment: I am 100 percent sure that the code should work! But it does not and I can not understand why. And there is no public variable.

Comment: That's really weird. Can you share the file? with just that part?

Comment: I found the Problem. Thanks

Comment: What was the problem? IF you post it ans answer, it may help others in the future

Comment: I posted the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Problem in my code.
I had a merge() function after WrapText.
I should put the .WrapText() function after the merge() not before.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the range:

```vb
Dim v_row  As Long
Dim RangeW As Range
    
v_row = 4
Set RangeW = Sheets(1).Range("B" & CStr(v_row))

RangeW.WrapText = True
```

Comment: Then, most likely, something else is going on. Check your code in a new workbook.

Comment: I found the Problem. Thanks

Comment: - and that was?